# Parse JSON (ISO8601) date string

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I can create a JavaScript date object with:

```
var d=new Date('2012-08-07T07:47:46Z');
document.write(d);
```

This will write the date using the browser's time zone. But I should be able to do (no 'Z'):

```
var d=new Date('2012-08-07T07:47:46');
document.write(d);
```

This returns the same as above, but according to the ISO8601 standard, a string without a timezone (e.g. +01:00) and without 'Z', the date should be considered in the local time zone. So the second example above should write the datetime as 7:47am.

I am getting a datetime string from a server and I want to display exactly that datetime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I found this script works well. It extends the Date.parse method.

https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601/

```
Date.parse('2012-08-07T07:47:46');
```

It doesn't work on the `new Date()` constructor however.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, Javascript doesn't play well with the ISO8601.

Use this function to convert to the desired format:

```
function ISODateString(d) {
  function pad(n){
    return n<10 ? '0'+n : n
  }
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
  + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}
var d = new Date();
print(ISODateString(d));
```

Taken from: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date#Example.3A_ISO_8601_formatted_dates)

Comment: This creates an ISO date string, it doesn't parse it